# Google place autocomplete API with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to implement auto search for address in my App using SwiftUI. Google tutorial are based on UIKit, I was hoping if someone has tried and can guide me to the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this code; it works for me.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import GooglePlaces


struct PlacePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var address: String

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PlacePicker>) -> GMSAutocompleteViewController {

        let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autocompleteController.delegate = context.coordinator


        let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) |
          UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue))!
        autocompleteController.placeFields = fields

        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .address
        filter.country = "ZA"
        autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
        return autocompleteController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PlacePicker>) {
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

        var parent: PlacePicker

        init(_ parent: PlacePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(place.description.description as Any)
                self.parent.address =  place.name!
                self.parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }

        func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
            print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }

        func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you integrate this into a view?

Comment: @Bonteq
.sheet(isPresented: $shouldOpenPlacePicker) {
     PlacePicker(address: $address)
}